# determine the number of characters printed to an output stream in java

Tags: java, c, stream

Is there any way to determine the number of characters printed to an output stream in java?

Like for example in C the printf returns the number of characters printed in that particular statement.

```
int i=printf("hello");
printf(i);
```

the above piece of code would print hello and 4;

is there any way to achieve the same in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing so you know the string to be displayed. Simple is that you get the string length.

```
string str="Hello World!";
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(str.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this information, then I'd suggest using Jakarta Commons [CountingOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html). However, I'd be surprised if you need this information on the level of an individual print statement, so perhaps you could describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve.

One thing you **should never do** is count the number of characters in the string that you write. Unless, of course, you can guarantee that the characters in your string are exactly represented by single bytes in the output stream. Now, and forever in the future, so that you don't end up with a hard-to-find bug when someone starts handing you strings with accented characters or Cyrillic.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries that can help.  Google Guava has a [CountingOutputStream](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CountingOutputStream.html) that wraps an `OutputStream` and provides a `getCount()` method. This returns the bytes written, and so is dependent on the encoding. See @parsifal's answer for why you need to care.  It doesn't provide the `PrintStream` interface, however. Jakarta Commons IO provides a similar class with the same name.  You could do:

```
OutputStream os = ...;
CountingOutputStream cos = new CountingOutputStream(os);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(cos);
// write to ps.
ps.close();
long count = cos.getCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
String s= "hello";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use the `length()` function from the regular Strings library/API. I am not sure if there is another way or a simpler way. Would love to know though!